# Verifying that a kubernetes pod is deleted using client-go

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, client-go

I am trying to ensure that a pod is deleted before proceeding with another Kubernetes Operation. So the idea I have is to Call the Pod Delete Function and then call the Pod Get Function.

```
// Delete Pod
err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(tr.namespace).Delete(podName, &metav1.DeleteOptions{})

if err != nil {
   ....
}

pod, err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(tr.namespace).Get(podName, &metav1.DeleteOptions{})

// What do I look for to confirm that the pod has been deleted?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`err != nil && errors.IsNotFound(err)`

Also this is silly and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I am open to better approaches. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Set the delete to foreground mode, like in https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go#L158-L161. Then it will block until it completes.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely is a better approach :)